# Listen tabs changes from a UITabBar Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I have a UITabBar with two tabs (so one view controller per tab). I want to listen in one of the controllers, when the other tab is pressed because I am implementing the method viewWillDisappear and I want to execute some code only if the view controller disappear because the user leaves the screen (UITabViewController) and not if only switch tabs.